# Mikrotik и HTTPs

Tags: firewall, mikrotik

работает ли firewall с https  ..  суть такая,  режу спам сервера майл ру и Яндексов всяких,  а спам пока не шибко убавляется. 
пишу правило  такое
chain input  protocol tcp content an.yandex.ru action reset reject with tcp reset

Answer (score 2):

С https не работает ни "content", ни L7 фильтр, ни родной WebProxy. Что, в принципе, логично.
По вашему случаю: в цепочке `input` фильтруется трафик предназначенный для роутера, а не транзитный, для этого используется `chain=forward`. Лучший вариант для Вас - создать `address-list` с ip адресами для блокировки, и его вешать на правила файерволла.
Например, для блокировки соц. сетей, составляется скрипт, который на основании заданных регулярных выражений автоматически добавляет и обновляет список ip адресов серверов соц. сетей, при попытке доступа к ним, и уже по этому списку идет блокировка. [Здесь](https://spw.ru/forum/threads/filtracija-https-trafika-v-seti.1197/) эта тема обсуждалась и есть примеры скриптов блокировки.

Comment: Работает, если попадется sni